# SUMPRODUCT on all sheets with sheet multiplier

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have multiple sheets that have the same layout but have different products and quantities on each sheet.

Then I have a different sheet that I'm using to total all the other sheets quantities per product I'm using this formula
`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&D$8:D$10&"'!B3:B6"),B3,INDIRECT("'"&D$8:D$10&"'!A3:A6")))` Which works fine.

[image]

[image]

How can I sum all the product quantities from the same sheet more than once, For example if I add the number of times I want to multiply the sheet In column `E` next to each sheet name and I put a qty of 2 in `E8` it would then double the quantity for that sheet well still summing all the other sheets.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Named Ranges for this. Give the Cell "E8" a name - "**Takeoff1_Multiplier**" and in the Sheet Takeoff1, go to cell "A3" and in the formula bar enter 
 the formula `=1*Takeoff1_Multiplier`.

Now, when you change the value in "E8", the value in "A3" will be multiplied.

If you don't want to use a formula in the Column A in the Takeoff1 sheet, use the formula in column c as `=A3*Takeoff1_Multiplier` and drag this formula for all the rows.

**Resources:**

**Named Range:** https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT($E8:$10*SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&D$8:D$10&"'!B3:B6"),B3,INDIRECT("'"&D$8:D$10&"'!A3:A6")))
or
=SUMPRODUCT($E8:$10,SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&D$8:D$10&"'!B3:B6"),B3,INDIRECT("'"&D$8:D$10&"'!A3:A6")))
```

Both methods should work.  Basically you are weighting the results of each sumif sheet result by the corresponding number n your table before taking the final sum/grand total.